# How do I prevent a user from seeing a list of databases and tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, privileges

I'm using MySQL version 5.7.25 on Google Cloud.

I revoked all privileges:

```
REVOKE ALL ON *.* FROM 'user1';
```

I added SELECT privileges on one table:

```
GRANT SELECT ON database1.table1 TO 'user1';
```

I check privileges using:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user1'

Result:
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user1'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT SELECT ON `database1`.`table1` TO 'user1'@'%'
```

Now 'user1' cannot access other tables. However, 'user1' can still see a list of databases and tables using:

```
SHOW DATABASES
SHOW TABLES
```

I've tried using:

```
REVOKE SHOW DATABASES ON *.* FROM 'user1';
```

In the documentation, this seems to be the command that I want to revoke.  However, this has no additional effect on privileges because the USAGE privilege overrides this SHOW DATABASES privilege.

I've seen suggestions to use "skip-show-database" on startup, but this turns off the SHOW DATABASES command for all users.

How can I limit a user to only see DATABASES and TABLES that are usable?  Or how can I completely turn off those commands for a single user?

Comment: What happens if you remove the grant option: revoke all, grant option on 'user1'

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL documentation for the `SHOW DATABASES` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-databases.html):

```
If the server was started with the --skip-show-database option, you cannot use this statement at all unless you have the SHOW DATABASES privilege
```

The `skip_show_database` flag is on the [list of supported flags for Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#mysql-s).